# Vcc of UCC289 confusion

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am looking at the circuit shown in the page 6 - [Document](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluu407a/sluu407a.pdf)

The circuit is as shown -
[image: Circuit]

The IC (PWM controller) used is the UCC289. The Vcc/Vdd (supply) is a max of 16V approx as per the datasheet. But, here we are feeding it almost 36-72V. How is that even possible ? The supply(36V) is fed via J1 and then finally to P_Bias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know where did you find a 16V, but from the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluu407a/sluu407a.pdf) Table 1 we have the characteristics of the PWM controller:
[image]

It seems to be OK for me!